# Async function passed as an argument in place of Promise, showing different results

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await, progressive-web-apps

I'm working with PWA, the cache.open method takes a promise as argument. while the normal flow of code looks like this:

```
event.waitUntil(
    caches.open().then().catch();
);
// output: as expected
```

I changed the argument to an explicit promise, and a async func. The promise is working the same way as expected but async function isn't.

For Promise

```
event.waitUntil(
    new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log('test');
        resolve();
    })
);

// output: as expected
```

For Async func

```
event.waitUntill(async () => await console.log('test'));

// output: no output
```

I want to know why async function isn't working as expected even though async itself returns a promise.

Comment: In the last example you are not passing a promise, you’re passing a function. You’ll get a promise if you call that function.

Comment: Ohh, why I haven't think of that. I can wrap the async in an IIFE to make it work. Thanks alot ..

Answer (score 1):

As Mark mentioned in the comment, async functions return promises when called. They aren't promises themselves. To make it work, you need to call that async function. You can think of async functions as promise generators. This should make it work:

```
const asyncFn = async () => await console.log('test')
event.waitUntill(asyncFn());
```